# split(String ,int )(int),what is the last (int) mean?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, rdd

Today,I am working with a project and there is a code about split()

```
val ageData = dataFile.map(line => line.split("s",1)(1))//ageDate：RDD[String]
```

I have known what split("s",1) is. My question is what does the "(1)" mean?

Comment: How do you extract an element from a List/Array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line.split("s",1)(1)` `(1)` is the `Array`'s index, for example:

`"abab".split("b", 2)`

> Array(a, ab)

so `"abab".split("b", 2)(1)` will be `ab`

Another thing need to call out is `line.split("s",1)(1)` this will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

This is caused you are setting the **split limit**(`line.split("s",1)`) is `1`, it's means the array's size will be `1`. so when you with **array** index `1`, this will throw this **Exception**. it should be `line.split("s",1)(0)` or `line.split("s",2)(1)`